# bitxor, solve equation, boolean logic

Tags: math, logic, bit-manipulation, equation

I have the equation:

```
C = A^b + (2*A)^b + (4*A)^b.
```

Where C and A are known, but b is unknown. How to find b?
All numbers are 8 bit bytes. Is there any possible method much faster than brute-force?

Comment: a^b there bitxor(a,b)

Comment: so what is "*" supposed to be - integer multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

Does the + sign indicate addition on bytes and * multipication, *with overflowing bits discarded*? If so, I think the answer is

```
b = C ^ (A + 2 * A + 4* A)
```

How to reach that conclusion :

```
C = A^b + (2*A)^b + (4*A)^b
```

hence

```
C^b = A^b^b + (2*A)^b^b + (4*A)^b^b = A + 2*A + 4*A
```

then

```
C^C^b = b = C^(A + 2*A + 4*A)
```

EDIT Just to make sure : This answer is **not correct**. Shame on me. I'll have to think more about it.

Comment: The first step is incorrect, XOR doesn't distribute over binary addition. For example take A = 0x00, C = 0x01, the actual answer is b = 0xAB.

Comment: @DPenner : you are right. Rats! I thought I had checked on that but obviously not well enough.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm taking the same assumptions: `+` and `*` are addition and multiplication with overflow ignored.*

### Look-up Table

This would probably be the fastest solution: Precompute the results, and store them in a look-up table. It would require 2<sup>16</sup> bytes of memory, or 64 kB.

### Guess, Check, Refine Method

Presented in C-family-like pseudocode:

```
byte Solve(byte a, byte c){
    byte guess = lastGuess = result = lastResult = 0;

    do {
        guess = lastGuess ^ lastResult ^ c;            //see explanation below
        result = a^guess + (2*a)^guess + (4*a)^guess; 
        lastGuess = guess;
        lastResult = result;
    } while (result != c);

    return guess;
}
```

The idea of this algorithm is that it makes a guess at what `b` is, then plugs it into the formula for a tentative result, and checks it against `c`. Whatever bits in the guess caused the result to differ from `c` are changed. This corresponds to the XOR of the last guess, last result, and `c` (if this statement is a little bit of a jump, I encourage you draw a truth table, and not just take my word for it!).

### Explanation

It works because changing a bit can only affect the results of that bit, and the more significant bits, but not lower bits (since when you do addition with pen and paper, the carries can propagate to the left). So in the worst case the algorithm takes 2 guesses to get the least significant bit correct, another guess for the 2nd lsb, another for the 3rd, etc. for a **maximum of 9 guesses** given any combination of `a` and `c`.

Here's an example trace from my test program:

```
a: 00001100
c: 01100111

Guess:  01100111
Result: 01000001
Guess:  01000001
Result: 00010111
Guess:  00110001
Result: 01100111

b: 00110001
```